# Can mvn install packages globally (e.g. command line tools like nutch)?

Tags: java, maven, command-line, package

Command line tools written in Ruby can be installed through RubyGems. Command line tools written in Node.js can be installed through NPM.

Does mvn offer similar functionality, or should I look to package systems like apt-get for installing Java command line tools?

Comment: gems and node modules are both installed through package managers.  npm stands for node package manager.

Comment: Maven usually download any dependencies that are needed to build an artefact. I am not sure what is your question. But maybe this would help. Take a look at the maven-exec plugin, http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html